# Xcode ggT - Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: xcode

I wanted to implement an easy ggT algorithm but Xcode drives me nuts...

```
int ggT(int a, int b){
    if (b==0)
        return a;

    else
        ggT(b, a%b);
}
```

I understand why the error comes so I added a return -1; at the end and thought this will never be returned, but it gets returned every time.

```
int ggT(int a, int b){
    if (b==0)
        return a;

    else{
        ggT(b, a%b);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I also tried it in an other IDE (Netbeans) and it worked perfect. Can someone explain why this doesn't work in Xcode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling a function doesn't automatically return the results: you need to add a return before the recursive ggT call

```
int ggT(int a, int b){
    if (b==0)
        return a;

    else{
        return ggT(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you works, but I don't understand why this is needed? In my understanding this should work also without the return. Since as soon as b is 0 it returns a. (I mean it even works in other IDEs) anyway thank you for the fast reply

Comment: the problem is if you just call ggT its return value is being ignored and execution continues to the end of the function, and there is no return statement. the compiler in other IDEs might not have warned you, but it wouldn't have worked as you expected